# Do I remove install disk whenasked to restart

Tags: system, restart

I am a new user. I am loading Ubuntu14.04LTS onto a Toshiba Tecra M5 with 3G RAM 2,16G Centrimo Nvidia Quadro NVS11om Graphic.
I am installing with a DVD, so bootup set to CD-ROM to start install in BIOS
When install completes it wants to restart the computer.
Do I remove the install DVD and reset boot to HDD on restart or leave as is and let it restart and reset boot later
Thanks

Comment: If you do not it will prompt for you to remove it (after you tell it to reboot)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to change the boot order in Bios, i.e. you keep DVD as the first, so YES, remove the installation media. However next time you turn your machine on with any bootable media inserted it will load from the DVD/CD.

Comment: Thanks Rusian, I removed the DVD pressed the restart now and nothing happened. So I forced a shut down, reset the BIOS to HDD and it appeared to start Ubuntu, icons appeared on the top right of the screen, it asked for my password but when I put the password in and pressed enter the computer froze with the purple desktop screen and Unbutu 14.04LTS in the bottom left hand corner and that's it Any idea's

Comment: I have no idea of what happened. would you press CTRL + ALT + F1 and see are you able to login?